# Graphing a paraboloid produces some imperfections using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I would like to plot the following bounded paraboloid using `tikzpicture`: `z = 3x^2 + 3y^2 - 3`.

This is what I got so far:

[image: Paraboloid]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{2.2cm}
{0.5cm}
{16.5cm}
{23.42cm}
{30pt}
{1cm}
{0pt}
{2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\large \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xmin=-1.5,
            ymin=-1.5,
            zmin=-3.5,
            xmax=1.5,
            ymax=1.5,
            zmax=1,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            view={145}{10},
            clip=false,
            axis on top,
            legend style={cells={align=left}}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=70,samples y=50,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=-1:1,restrict z to domain=-3:0] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{3*r*r-3});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Anyway, there are some imperfections on the right side:**

[image: Imperfections]

If I try increasing the samples of the `y` coordinate the imperfections are reduced but after `samples y=50` it generates me error of size.

I believe that the figure does not finish closing completely due to some problem in the way of defining the parameters but I can't figure it out why is this happening.

How can it be solved in a easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imperfections seem to be linked to where the domain of `t` starts and ends. By moving that to the 'back' of the plot, we make them invisible. Also, by taking `domain y=-1:1` you plot all point twice, a domain of `0:1` is sufficient. This also greatly reduces the needed `samples y`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,very thick,only marks,mark=*}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            legend style={font=\tiny},
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xmin=-1.5,
            ymin=-1.5,
            zmin=-3.5,
            xmax=1.5,
            ymax=1.5,
            zmax=1,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            zlabel = $z$,
            view={145}{10},
            clip=false,
            axis on top,
            legend style={cells={align=left}}
        ]
            % Field
%            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=70,samples y=50,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=0:360,domain y=-1:1,restrict z to domain=-3:1] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{3*r*r-3});
            \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,samples=72,samples y=20,variable=t,variable y=r,domain=-225:360-225,domain y=0:1] ({r*cos(t)},{r*sin(t)},{3*r*r-3});
            \addlegendentry{$f(x,y)$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 3 minutes to accept the answer hehe. This is great because you also quit the `z` domain! How did you know the range of the angle `-225:360-225`? Because if we use `0:360` the imperfections are now on the left side.

Comment: Well if you calculate the coordinate for `t=0` then the `y` coordinate is zero. If you fill in `t=225` you're at the 'back' of the plot as seen from this view. With `view={145}{10}` an even better domain would be `domain=-235:125` (`0-145-90:360-145-90`) so the border is exactly behind the `z`-axis.